# Passport JWT not returning right user

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jwt, passport.js

So I got this strategy to extract jwt and return user from request. This is the code:

```
module.exports = function(passport) {
  var opts = {};
  opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken();
  opts.secretOrKey = process.env.JWT_SECRET;
  passport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts, function(jwt_payload, done) {
    console.log('PAYLOAD RECEIVED: ')
    console.log(jwt_payload)
    User.findOne({id: jwt_payload.id}, function(err, user) {
      if (err) {
        return done(err, false);
      }
      if (user) {
        console.log('USER ' + user.username)
        done(null, user);
      } else {
        console.log('ELSE')
        done(null, false);
      }
    });
  }));
};
```

Whatever the payload is I'm always getting the first User from the database.
I saw all tutorials use `jwt_payload.id` but when I do `console.log(jwt_payload.id)` it's returning undefined, and when I try to extract ID like this `jwt_payload._doc._id` I get the right ID when I do `console.log` but user is not found. This is the code for that:

```
module.exports = function(passport) {
  var opts = {};
  opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken();
  opts.secretOrKey = process.env.JWT_SECRET;
  passport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts, function(jwt_payload, done) {
    console.log('PAYLOAD RECEIVED: ')
    let id = jwt_payload._doc._id
    console.log(id)
    User.findOne({id: id}, function(err, user) {
      if (err) {
        return done(err, false);
      }
      if (user) {
        console.log('USER ' + user.username)
        done(null, user);
      } else {
        console.log('USER NOT FOUND')
        done(null, false);
      }
    });
  }));
};
```

The output is :
PAYLOAD RECEIVED:
**59a44431fcd0a9495f64f94c** (That is the right ID)
USER NOT FOUND

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your query is wrong!

Try to call `User.findById(id, function(err, user) {})`

Or

`User.findOne({_id: id}, function(err, user) {})`

Hope it helps!